# WooCommerce Subscription plugin update custom table after payment made

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, subscriptions

I have install [WooCommerce Subscription](https://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/) commercial plugin and every thing working fine like recurring payment. what I would like is when a subscription is made, to update that subscription in my custom table.

Even every time when user subscription is renewed, i would like that the amount get updated in my custom table.

Reference: [Subscription developper documentation](https://docs.woothemes.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-extensions/subscriptions/developer-docs/)

Comment: Can you provide link of plugin you are using? and does that plugin provide any hook to trigger event when subscription is made? Can you provide structure of your custom table? Provide more detail please

Comment: plugin url is https://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/ and what i want that when ever recurring payment made i wan to update it on my custom table

Comment: i want the solution

Comment: @HimanshuSundariyal What you asking is unclear and without any code that you can provide this question is going to stay unanswered. Then first you will need to copy [woocommerce templates (see this)](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) into your active child theme or theme folder (renaming it "woocommerce"). Then read the dev docs (link in your question). After that you must need to copy the right template from Subscription plugin templates folder into the woocommerce theme folder, in the right place - Search a little over internet. Update your question, with some code…

Comment: the docs have a link to a Subscriptions [action reference](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/). The action you probably would need is `processed_subscription_payment`. If you add a function to that it would be triggered any time a subscription payment is made.

Answer (score -1):

I was in the same trouble and this solution work for me ! 
Add this code at the end of your functions.php file, which is located in “wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/:”

```
/**
 * Auto Complete all WooCommerce orders.
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}
```